# Issue faced reading an entry name from Tar InputStream

Tags: inputstream, tar, byte-order-mark

Facing problem regarding reading archive file recursively. I have created one recursive program which reads entry name from tar file or zip etc and will exit when some xyz extension found.

The code executes absolutely fine with proper entry name including archives having extension(eg, .zip,.tar,.tar.gz,.tgz), but it throws junk characters if the entry name is archive, but archive has no extension.

**Eg: One archive inside another archive with no extension, viz, Ming_2nd.tar contains archive Ming_2nd which is an archive format**

The following are the code and output.

```
public static String readTar4SrcType(TarInputStream tarInpStream) throws Exception{     
    TarEntry tarEntry = null;
    int cnt = 0;
    try {
        tarEntry = tarInpStream.getNextEntry();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        src = "Other";
    }

    while (tarEntry != null) {
        cnt++;
        if (tarEntry.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Inside directory 4 Tar File..");
        } else {                
            if (src.equals("tex") || src.equals("doc") || src.equals("docx")) {
                break;                  
            } else {

                String entryName = tarEntry.getName();
                System.out.println("entryName : " + entryName);

                if(entryName.lastIndexOf("/")!=-1){
                    if (entryName.endsWith(".tar") || entryName.endsWith(".tar.gz") || entryName.endsWith(".tgz")){
                        readTar4SrcType(tarInpStream);
                        tarInpStream = null;
                    } else if (entryName.endsWith(".zip")) {
                        ZipInputStream zins = new ZipInputStream(tarInpStream);
                        readZIP4SrcType(zins);
                        zins = null;
                    } else if (entryName.endsWith(".tex")) {
                        System.out.println("TEX found...break");
                        src = "tex";
                        break;
                    } else if (entryName.endsWith(".doc") || entryName.endsWith(".docx")) {
                        System.out.println("DOC found...break");
                        src = "doc";
                        break;
                    } else {
                        src = "Other";
                    }
                } else{
                    if(entryName.endsWith(".tex")){
                        src = "tex";
                        System.out.println("TEX found...break");
                        break;
                    } else if(entryName.endsWith(".doc") || entryName.endsWith(".docx")){
                        System.out.println("DOC found...break");
                        src = "doc";
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid file format");
                        src = "Other";                          
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        tarEntry = tarInpStream.getNextEntry();
    }

    if(cnt==0) {
        src = "Other";
    }

    return src;
}

 ??#????+^??NW}??C????????Y?c?>?uM??1??v?Q7????;Z8?DQ=?o??
Invalid file format
entryName : ?zv????????????3?^:??????|?>t?%oN???.5;??%z????_??kiqFt??l\?X??,m?????b
'?x(???????J5??j?x?%??
Invalid file format
entryName : +Dw???m?-?)????Ck??????4???>? ?e/???????^#????2?x$???z????????
entryName : ?~??Z
@5\?????&J7??{c?w{
```

> Please provide me the solution as I am stuck for many days.

Comment: **Still not received any update on this**

Comment: Still waiting for reply